# How to remove UISwipeGestureRecognizer From Navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, uiswipegesturerecognizer

My problem is related With UISwipeGestureRecognizer.I Add UISwipeGestureRecognizer for toggling the menu screen for the first screen. This is my code

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizernavle = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
[gestureRecognizernavle setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizernavle];
```

But the same function is calling while the swapping navigation bar on the next view.
I put the following code for removing SwipeGestureRecognizer

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

But this code is not working. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove the gesture recogniser from the navigation bar.

```
while (self.navigationController.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers.count) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar  removeGestureRecognizer:[self.navigationController.navigationBar.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

It will remove all gesture recognisers from the navigation bar, you can put the conditions if you want to remove some some.

Enjoy. :)